# Is there a proper way to create a const from an enum value in a crate?

Tags: rust

Create a crate:

```
cargo new --lib constenum
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
#[repr(u16)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
}
pub const CRATE_ONE: u16        = MyEnum::ONE as u16;
pub const CRATE_TWO: u16        = MyEnum::TWO as u16;
```

**tests/lib.rs**

```
extern crate constenum;

#[test]
fn f() {
    let test_x = [0; constenum::CRATE_TWO as usize];
    // the above causes a compile error below

    // error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
    //    --> src/lib.rs:7:28
    //    |
    // 10 |
    //    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unimplemented constant expression: enum variants
    //    |
    // note: for repeat count here
    //     --> tests/lib.rs:5:22
    //    |
    // 5  |     let test_x = [0; constenum::CRATE_TWO as usize];
    //    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

If I put the same code into **examples/main.rs**, which is very similar to the tests but does not use the crate, it succeeds:

```
#[repr(u16)]
pub enum ExampleEnum {
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
}
pub const EXAMPLE_ONE: u16      = ExampleEnum::ONE as u16;
pub const EXAMPLE_TWO: u16      = ExampleEnum::TWO as u16;

fn main() {
    let example_x = [0; EXAMPLE_TWO as usize];
}
```

Comment: I *suspect* this is a bug, but I'm *very* sure that error message pointing at nothing is a bug too, so [I filed that](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38875).

Comment: This works as of Rust 1.18, released Jun 8, 2017.